# Tensorflow: Loss and Accuracy curves showing similar behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras with the Tensorflow backend to train a modified Resnet-50 that classifies objects into 15 categories. I am using the Adam optimizer and I tried learning rates of 0.001 and 0.01 but got similar results.

The problem I am facing is that the loss and accuracy both show similar behavior (in the training and validation datasets). They both go up or down at similar times and I expected to get higher accuracies as loss went down. What can be causing this behavior?

Here are some Tensorboard curves from my last run:
[image: Training Set Accuracy and Loss]

[image: Validation Set Accuracy and Loss]

Edit:
The code for the model is the following:

```
#Model creation:
def create_model(possible_labels):
    rn50 = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights=None)
    layer_name = rn50.layers[-2].name
    model = Model(rn50.input, 
            Dense(len(possible_labels))(rn50.get_layer(layer_name).output))
    adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
            optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='the_best_you_ever_had', 
                             verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    tensorboard = TensorBoard()
    return model, [checkpointer, tensorboard]

model, checkpointers = create_model(labels)

#Dataset generation:
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
vertical_flip=True,
channel_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2
)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
'data\\train',
target_size=(224, 224),
batch_size=32,
class_mode='categorical'
)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
'data\\validation',
target_size=(224, 224),
batch_size=32,
class_mode='categorical'
)

#Model training:
model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=5000,
epochs=50,
validation_data=val_generator,
callbacks=checkpointers
)
```

Comment: Could you please share your code as well ?

Comment: That seems to be the space of 1 epoch only.... are you sure it's not a bug, an infinity or a nan appearing somewhere?

Comment: Checked for possible divisions by zero, all-zeros rows in the matrices (which could be caused by relu), negative roots and other math errors?

Comment: What specifically in the code? The model creation and compilation? And those graphs are of 50 epochs, the x-axis is the epochs. The problem is of image classification so I don't think there are all-zeros or zero divisions in the input.

Comment: the reason is a bug in the code, as assuming typical meaning of word loss in this context, when it is 0 - the accuracy is 100, since these two numbers do not match it means that your implementation is wrong (and since it is not part of the question we cannot provide any other insights).

Comment: I have edited the post so it includes the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error in my code and it was the fact that I was just using the default (linear) activation in my added last layer. I switched it to a softmax activation (as it is a classification and not a regression problem) by doing this in the code:

```
model = Model(rn50.input, 
        Dense(len(possible_labels), activation='softmax')
        (rn50.get_layer(layer_name).output))
```

and then the curves started behaving as expected and I achieved 96% accuracy.